# Adding a "CC" recipient in Node eml file

Tags: node.js, eml

I am creating eml files in my Node backend using an npm package called "eml-format", and I'm trying to determine what syntax I would use to designate a "cc" on an email. This is the example they provide, in terms of what you should pass in when building the eml file:

```
let data = {
  from: "no-reply@bar.com",
  to: {
    name: "Foo Bar",
    email: "foo@bar.com"
  },
  subject: "Winter promotions",
  text: "Lorem ipsum...",
  html: '<html><head></head><body>Lorem ipsum...<br /><img src="nodejs.png" alt="" /></body></html>',
  attachments: [
    {
      name: "sample.txt",
      contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
      data: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget elit turpis. Aliquam lorem nunc, dignissim in risus at, tempus aliquet justo..."
    },
    {
      name: "nodejs.png",
      contentType: "image/png",
      data: fs.readFileSync("nodejs.png"),
      inline: true
    }
  ]
};
```

How would I add a section to "cc" a second email address? I tried making the assignment for "to" an array, with two separate objects. But this didn't work. I also tried adding a key/value pair for `{Cc: "sample@email.com"}` to `data` but this didn't show up in the final eml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it doesn't appear to have support for CC-style recipients.

It may be worth asking the maintainer to add it to bring the lib to closer parity with [the spec they reference](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt).

Additionally, you may be able to add the functionality yourself with something like:

```
if (typeof data.cc != "undefined") {
  data.headers["Cc"] = (typeof data.cc == "string" ? data.cc : emlformat.toEmailAddress(data.cc));
}
```

https://github.com/papnkukn/eml-format/blob/f7648b54f8d8b713bf58be8130b3f42f3ec2e674/lib/eml-format.js#L261-L267

Comment: Great suggestion, @imjared. I added the block to their source code and it worked like a charm. Many thanks.